# How to resolve conflict of comboboxes?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm making an app with JavaFX and Scene Builder.

**-I have one combo box for selecting font size (id - size)**

**-I have one combo box for selecting font family (id - font selector)**

**-I have a label (id - front label)**

> ***Problem #1:*** When I I click on Combobox with fThe drop-down. Drop-down list appears only after a second. It seems like it works
>   slow
>
> ***Problem #2:*** When I click on combobox with font family and choose some font it doesn't apply to the label, but font family applies when
>   I click on combobox and choose font second time. In this case,  I
>   should pick a font two times in a row to apply a font to my label
>
> ***Problem a #3(Main problem):*** I have conflict of comboboxes. When I choose a font family it applies to the label, but when  I choose font
>   size from other combobox size also applies but after that font family
>   of the label become default. Same situation occurs when I pick font
>   size and then pick font family from other combobox.

It seems that only one combobox can be applied to the label.

**How to resolve these problems?**

> *All code is in the Controller
>
> *Problem #3 is the primordial one.

[Video](https://mega.nz/#!WdcXTC6D!Bo3xl-Qj-9RKZkLW-fpF5WjjGJ3F3UeSumeHOpvQL8c)

```
@FXML  private ComboBox<String> fontSelector;
@FXML  private ComboBox<Integer> size;
@FXML  private Label fontLabel;

//create array of font sizes
ObservableList<Integer> fontSizes = FXCollections.observableArrayList(8, 
10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 24, 30, 36, 40, 48, 60, 72);

//get fonts from system
ObservableList<String> fonts = 
FXCollections.observableArrayList(Font.getFamilies());

//getting Controller variables and methods through Context class
Controller cont = Context.getInstance().getController();


@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

//register FontController in  Context Class
Context.getInstance().setFontController(this);

 //bind text from textfield to label
 fontLabel.textProperty().bind(fontTextfield.textProperty());


 //show fonts' actual look in combobox list
 fontSelector.setCellFactory((ListView<String> listView) -> {
  final ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<>(){
    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
      super.updateItem(item, empty);
      if (item != null) {
        setText(item);
        setFont(new Font(item, 14));
      }
    }
  };
  return cell;
});


fontSelector.setItems(fonts);
size.setItems(fontSizes);
size.setOnAction(e -> updateFontSize());
}
```

Method that applies font size to label from combobox

```
private void updateFontSize() {
fontLabel.setFont(Font.font(size.getValue()));
}
```

Method that applies font family from combobox to the label

```
public void changeLabel(ActionEvent event) {    
fontSelector.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, 
oldValue, newValue) -> fontLabel.setFont(Font.font(newValue, 
FontWeight.NORMAL, 35)));
}
```

**EDIT:**

I assume that conflict of comboboxes appears here:

```
fontSelector.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, 
oldValue, newValue) -> fontLabel.setFont(Font.font(newValue, 
FontWeight.NORMAL, 35)));
```

How to refactor that line of code to make it work but without concrete font size after FontWeight.Normal in brackets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to combine both values of the `ComboBox`es to create the font. You only use a single one each though. As for the delay when opening the font `ComboBox`: this is probably caused by the fact that multiple `Font`s need to be loaded. You could replace the `ComboBox` type parameter `Font` and preload the fonts.

To use a custom display for the font in the `ComboBox` button area too, you need to use set the same cell type that is created by the `cellFactory` as `buttonCell`.

Use a binding for the font based on the 2 `value` properties of the `ComboBox`es instead

#### Example

```
private static Font getFont(Font font, Integer size) {
    return Font.font(font == null ? null : font.getFamily(), size == null ? -1d : size.doubleValue());
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    ComboBox<Font> fontSelector = new ComboBox<>();
    fontSelector.getItems().addAll(Font.getFamilies().stream().map(name -> Font.font(name, 14)).toArray(Font[]::new));

    ComboBox<Integer> size = new ComboBox<>();
    size.getItems().addAll(10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 24, 30, 36, 40, 48, 60, 72);

    Label fontLabel = new Label("Hello World");
    
    // bind font based on size/family
    fontLabel.fontProperty()
            .bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> getFont(fontSelector.getValue(), size.getValue()),
                    fontSelector.valueProperty(), size.valueProperty()));

    class FontListCell extends ListCell<Font> {

        @Override
        public void updateItem(Font item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item != null) {
                setText(item.getFamily());
                setFont(item);
            } else {
                setText("");
                setFont(Font.font(14));
            }
        }
    }
    
    fontSelector.setCellFactory(lv -> new FontListCell());
    fontSelector.setButtonCell(new FontListCell());

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(fontSelector, size, fontLabel), 300, 500);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a combobox conflict. What happens is exactly what you coded.

By reading the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/Font.html#font-double-) of `Font.font( size )` :

> Searches for an appropriate font **based on the default font family name** and given font size.

Actually the problem is pretty simple. Change the method

```
private void updateFontSize() {
   // Here we retrieve the current font family name in order to not apply the default one.
   fontLabel.setFont(Font.font(fontLabel.getFont().getName(), size.getValue()));
}
```

It is the same idea when you change the font family name. Retrieve the size of your label's font and apply the new font family name with the previous font size.

Comment: I've tried your piece of code, but I've got an error [image] (https://imgur.com/a/oSn9wmf)

Comment: I've also tried to change Combobox to  @FXML Combobox<String>  size; but nothing happaned

Comment: Your problem was because the method `setFont(String pFontName, double pSize)` does not accept `Integer` as second parameter (the size) but `double`. By the way, fabian's answer is cleaner.

Comment: The `setFont` method takes a `Font` argument, not a `String` and `double`. You need to call `setFont(Font.font(fontLabel.getFont().getName(), size.getValue()))`.

Comment: @Slaw, totally `true`, I forget the `Font` class, I will update my post (or should I remove it considering the Fabian's one is better ?).